# Use SQL statements to construct an aggregator to calculate the data sum of a matrix

Tags: sql, postgresql, matrix

I have recently tried to construct an aggregator to calculate the sum of the entire table data. Do you have any opinions?

Following is my table structure and data：

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
room INT NOT NULL,
salary INT NOT NULL, 
time INT NOT NULL);



 id | room | salary | time 
----+------+--------+------
  1 |  101 |    100 |    7
  2 |  205 |    150 |    8
  3 |  304 |    160 |    7
  4 |  106 |    200 |    8
```

I want to calculate the total of the entire table data by constructing an aggregator so that its output looks like this:

```
sum
------
1366
```

Are there any good solutions?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us the DBMS you are using, but in standard SQL you could "unpivot" the columns using a lateral join and then sum the result:

```
select sum(t.val)
from matrix
  cross join lateral ( values (room), (salary), (time) ) as t(val);
```